# Tone.js: How do I loop a sound seamlessly?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api, tone.js

I've got a short, crossfaded ambient sound clip running on a loop using Tone.js. Trouble is, there's an audible gap between the end of one playback and the beginning of the next.

I know it's possible to achieve a seamlessly crossfaded loop in Howler.js using audio sprites, but I'm not sure how to do it in Tone.js (and I'd rather stick with this library if possible).

Does anybody out there know how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you loading audio from a file? If yes, then which format?

Comment: @HankMoody It's from an MP3 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid discontinuities in looped audio, you need to crossfade the end of the loop with the beginning of it.  If your program is only working with a fixed set of loops, you can pre-render the crossfade into the clip using an audio editor like Audacity or a DAW like Pro Tools or Reaper.

If you have a general-purpose app that needs to work with user-supplied audio, then you'll need to write code to mix the end of the loop fading out with the beginning of the loop fading in.

Answer (score 1):

Looping seamlessly MP3 tracks is difficult, but not impossible. MP3 files contain an additional padding that is decoded as audio data by decoders. I would recommend one of these two options to work around the paddings:

1. Prepare seamless MP3 loops with a special software. You can read more about that here: https://www.compuphase.com/mp3/mp3loops.htm
2. Switch to a different format: AAC (best support in all browsers, but there still might be some issues with paddings, can be overcame), OPUS, OGG. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gapless_playback#Prerequisites

Comment: Oh, but this is a subtle gotcha. Thank you, I will look into this!

Comment: Also make sure to cut the end and beginning of the loop at a [zero crossing](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/select_menu_at_zero_crossings.html).